# How do I store the content of a dataset in a string varialble?

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a dataset ds which contains around 37 k table records, i want to store the 1st one(to see a sample record) in a string variable. How do I do that?

Thanks,
Amrutha

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
private String DataRowToString(DataRow row, DataColumnCollection columns)
{
   StringBuilder rowStringBuilder = New StringBuilder();
   foreach (DataColumn dc in columns)
   {
      dataRowBuilder.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", dc.ColumnName, row(dc.Ordinal));
      dataRowBuilder.AppendLine();
   }

   return dataRowBuilder.ToString();
}

String rowString = ConvertDataRowToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0], ds.Tables[0].Columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `string row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString()`

If you want to display something more custom I'd advise

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];

string summary = "Field1 = " + row["Field1"] + "; Field2 = "+ row["Field2"]; //etc
```

I would also ask myself why I have a variable in memory containing 37k rows and if that's the only way to achieve what I need.

Comment: If I try to check the value of row in debug mode, it just says System.Data.Datarow, How do i see the actual content?

Comment: You can see the contents of a DataSet / DataTable / DataRow in debug mode

Comment: I just want to see the row content, is it not possible? Say it has 10 columns, i want to see the value of each column, whats the best method?

Comment: DataTables show a magnifying glass in debug mode which shows you the whole content of the table. I would have thought a DataSet allows you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

Dataset Visualizer Dialog Box
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d480bk47.aspx